# How to style nodes in d3 directed graph based on groups using reactjs

Tags: reactjs, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I'm using d3 to generate a force-directed graph based on this example: [Force-directed graph example in d3](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)

I'm implementing this in combination with React, in which d3 forces the directed graph and reactjs renders the visualization.

Now I would like to style (color) the nodes based on the groups they are assigned to. This is my data for the nodes:

```
var nodes = [
{"name":"node1","group":"2"},
{"name":"node2","group":"4"},
{"name":"node3","group":"5"}]
```

In this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Rom2BE/H2PkT/), they actually do the exact same thing, except without reactjs. However, I couldn't find any clear way to do this in combination with reactjs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally graphing library such as d3.js, plotly.js takes just layout and data. Color assignment to separate node is done internally. However, you can accomplish it by doing this:

Assuming this is your data:

```
const nodes = [{
    "name": "Vertex 5",
    "group": "1"
  },
  {
    "name": "Vertex 9",
    "group": "4"
  },
  {
    "name": "Vertex 15",
    "group": "5"
  }
];
```

You need to use the d3 api to create a mapping between your groups and the colors. You can do this by adding the following to your component that creates the nodes:

```
var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);
```

Then you can pass this mapping to the component which is responsible for creating your directed graph, i.e. in your case in the render method:

```
fill={color(d.group)}
```

This tells the fill attribute to get the filling from the mapping in the variable color, looking at every node via the variable d.

Comment: Your code snippet is the same as my data. But my question is, given the fact that I grouped my nodes in my data, how can I make sure they have a certain color using reactjs.

Comment: Sorry if my answer is off track, but if you want to give particular color to the specific node. you should have group name and color mapping somewhere.
I didn't know what color do you want for specific node that's why I used random function. you can have your own mapping

Comment: I use `var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory10);` for the mapping. Now the next step is to make sure reactjs renders the mapping and colors the nodes. I'm not sure, but I think it should be similar to a definition like `fill={() => color(d.group)}`. It doesn't work though.

Comment: I have made changes , if that does not fulfill your need please share react components code . I can answer well in that context

Comment: I found a way to accomplish what I wanted. stack26, is it good if I edit your answer (and your code) in order to indicate it as the right answer to the question?